# Is there an R equivalent of df.resample('D').mean()?

Tags: python, r, pandas, time-series

Basically the title is my question.

I have the data from dataloggers which are read hourly.
For my study 1 day step is enough.

Thus, in Python I would just use:

```
df.resample('D').mean()
```

But I do not know how to do it in R.